# Geo-location Search function

Tags: geolocation, location, business-catalyst

I was wondering if anyone has any information or a link to information/webapp/plug-in/software on creating a location based search function for a website. We use a platform called adobe business catalyst which is unfortunately being discontinued and we use a webapp the contains addresses of over 45000 locations that users can search for on the front end based off of a radius of their own location.

Any ideas, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share what platform you intend to use? Maybe Shopify?

Comment: the platform will either be Wordpress or something similar to BC, like treepl or siteglide but we havent nailed down which one to use yet cause we don't want to dive in without a solution for the problem yet.

Comment: Add tag for `Wordpress` to your question :)